# What is the distinctive characteristic/structure of Polish Space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the geometric structure of Polish space. While reading I came up with the wikipedia link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory

and on the second paragraph of the link it says:

A Polish space is a second countable topological space that is metrizable with a complete metric. Equivalently, it is a complete separable metric space whose metric has been "forgotten"

I did not understand the context of the word "forgotten". I think this relates to some concept which I am missing. Any comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Polish space in this context doesn't actually have a metric, but it is completely metrizable. I can think of two equivalent ways to view this statement:

1. Starting from a Polish space you can (non-uniquely) choose a metric which induces the topology, obtaining a complete metric space.
2. Starting from a complete metric space you can (uniquely) record the topology and then throw out the metric, to leave behind a Polish space.

There is probably a way of viewing the statement as somehow being about equivalence classes, but I would rather not get into it.

Comment: Excellent. Got it. Thanks a lot.